# Question on python text file read write using Win32com

Tags: python

I am reading a text file a.txt which has so many columns and i need the data in 5 columns.
I fetched it by reading and get data of 5 columns,but my question is how can I import these 5 columns data into one excel file having same column as in text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example explaining how to generate an excel file with the [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) python lib.

Using win32 would be ok but i personnaly prefer to use xlwt because it doesn't require excel to be installed on the machine.

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("My sheet")
for line in xrange(10):
    for col in xrange(5):
        ws.write(line, col, line*10+col)
wb.save('myfile.xls')
```

I hope it helps